# How to render format in pdf in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, pdf, report, render

I want the the table  to be displayed **in pdf** format .

we are using

```
format.html
format.json{render json: @user}
```

etc for generating html ,json format

Similarly

- I want to render the page as pdf .

so what steps are there if it is possible in rails???

Comment: Is it possible to use format.pdf {render :pdf } etc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another thing is [Prawn](http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/).

It seems more robust and support complex situations. So you may choose this to work with something sophisticated. Get the https://prawnpdf.org/manual.pdf here.
The API docs: https://prawnpdf.org/api-docs/2.3.0/

Thanks Glenn for pointing it out.

Comment: You want to use `Prawn`? or `Wicked_pdf`

Comment: Prawn but first I want working example I am not understanding the manuals and internet stuff...

Comment: The link is broken. This prawn? https://prawnpdf.org/api-docs/2.3.0/

Answer (score 14):

## Step one:

register PDF type for use in respond_to blocks

```
# config/mime_types.rb
Mime::Type.register "application/pdf", :pdf
```

## Step two:

in your controller respond to PDF format request

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json{render json: @user}
    format.pdf do
        # ...
        # here your PDF generating code
        # ...
        send_data(your_generated_pdf, filename: 'your_filename.pdf', type: 'application/pdf')
    end
end
```

For generating PDF you can use [pdfkit](https://github.com/pdfkit/pdfkit) with [wkthmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org), Prawn and some other. Refer to the respective documentations on their usage.

Starting from Rails 5:

## Step three:

add `gem 'responders'` as Rails 5 changelog says: "Remove respond_to/respond_with placeholder methods, this functionality has been extracted to the responders gem"

Comment: NoMethodError - undefined method `respond_to'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38600628/undefined-method-respond-to-in-rails-5-controller/38602666

Answer (score 7):

I think this might help [ https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf ]

You will always be able to use like `format.pdf` as long as your route supports `.:format` part. So just use that to capture the request for pdf. Then render the pdf using `wicked_pdf`.

The basic usage is showing there as below

```
def controller_action
    ... ... ...
    ... ... ...
    format.pdf do
        render :pdf => "file_name"
    end
end
```

Here is [another article](https://snikt.net/blog/2012/05/01/generating-pdfs-with-wicked_pdf/) might help to understand the usage.

Comment: Thanks for the article on wicked, although it was moved - http://www.snikt.net/blog/2012/04/26/wicked-pdf/

Answer (score 5):

Finally its done with `prawn` and `prawn-rails`. Here are the details.

To make my system ready

```
# Add this to your Gemfile
gem 'prawn'
gem 'prawn_rails'

# run
bundle install
```

I hit the url `http://localhost:3000/regions` i.e. to hit the `index` of `RegionsController` and it shows the page as pdf format.

I have a `Region` Model with a single attribute `name`. Has two entries in `regions` table.

```
[
 #<Region id: 1, name: "Region 1", ... >,
 #<Region id: 2, name: "Region 2", ... >
]
```

My Controller Method:

```
def index
    @regions = Region.all # Should return two region objects :)

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html # index.html.erb
        format.json { render json: @regions }
        format.pdf    # <---------- This will handle the pdf response
    end
end
```

I have created a view file in `views/regions/index.pdf.prawn`. Anyway the view file name format is `:action.pdf.prawn` and the view file is containing

```
prawn_document() do |pdf|
    @regions.each {|r| pdf.text r.name}
end
```

This will just output the name of Regions.

Thats it. You have your page in pdf format. Now just play with all other options provided by `Prawn` and `Prawn-Rails`. You can find some here - http://prawn-rails-demo.heroku.com/

Just thinking to write a series of blogs guiding how to use different pdf generation tool with rails 3.

Let me know if it solves your problem.

Comment: Why didn't you merge your second answer into the first one?

Comment: hmm... its around two years back but probably because second answer is just like saying "Hi" to `Prawn` and third answer is doing business with him along with a new partner `prawn_rails`. Didnt want to mix that up.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use templates, you can always use [the combine_pdf gem](https://github.com/boazsegev/combine_pdf) by itself (it has minor editing capabilities, such as tables and text boxes) or together with any of the aforementioned solutions, such as [Prawn](http://prawnpdf.org/api-docs/2.0/).