# Rails: How to call a Javascript function from HTML in render :pdf

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, render

I need to show a text result of an amount, and for this I'm using a javascript function "toWords". This function is working great when I use onInput or onClick, but I need to call this function when the document opens. So this is what I tried:

```
  <div class="label-field-pair3-text-area">
    <p id="demo"></p>

    </div>


<script type='text/javascript'>



document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = window.toWords("<%= @amount.to_f %>"); 

..... </script>
```

But this doesn't work. I also tried this:

```
 j(document).ready( function(){ text_amount();});
 function text_amount(){
  var i= getElementbyId('payment_text');
  i.val(toWords("<%= @amount.to_f %>"));}
```

And this:

```
   <div class="label-field-pair3-text-area" id='payment_text' onload = "text_amount(150)">
```

But none of this worked, and nothing is displayed.

UPDATE: When I removed render :pdf from controller, it worked. So the problem is in running this function onLoad upon rendering my PDF file.

Comment: can't you try `onload` callback on `body` tag?

Comment: What is your rendered-out version of the text_amount method?  Step through this in the chrome (or whatever browser you use) dev console and check it makes sense.

Comment: `@amount.to_f` might be returning nothing.. try putting this and see `<%= '1.0'.to_f %>` instead of `<%= @amount.to_f %>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm also having problems with render :pdf, so I'm using this instead:

```
    <%= link_to t('print'), "#", {:class  => 'grey-button-large themed_bg themed-dark-hover-background',  :href=>'javascript:printReceipt()'}%>
```

Then in script:

```
 function printReceipt()
{ 
  //$('#page-yield').printElement(); 
   var divName = "page-yield";
    var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
    var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

    document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

    window.print();

    document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}
```

This is a temporary solution that will open your file as a page and when the user clicks on print, it gets printed.

However, I advice you to check PRAWN:

http://www.sitepoint.com/pdf-generation-rails/

[How to render format in pdf in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120218/how-to-render-format-in-pdf-in-rails)

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll use your temporary solution for now, and I'll try PRAWN gem.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a mix of jquery and regular js there:  you define `i` with getElementById and then call the jquery object function `val()` on it.  `val()` needs to be called on a jquery object, which `i` is not.  Try this instead:

```
 function text_amount(){
   var i = $('#payment_text');
   i.val(toWords("<%= @amount.to_f %>"));
 }
```

or, more simply,

```
 function text_amount(){
   $('#payment_text').val(toWords("<%= @amount.to_f %>"));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the method **toWords** is loaded by

```
console.log(window.toWords);
```

before you use it

The html page load the script in sequence, if you add the method after you use it, it is undefined.