# Rails 4 No route matches [GET] when clicking on a link to open a PDF

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Rails 4 application, I'm showing a link to the PDF files. The user should be able to click the link and see the PDF. 
What I got is the error **No route matches [GET]:**  "/assets/documents/pdf/..."

I don't know what to do if I need to add in the routes and controller something?

My controller:

```
class SearchesController < ApplicationController

  require 'net/http'

  def index
    if params[:search].present?
      url = "http://localhost:3003/api/search?q=" + params[:search][:keyword]
      uri = URI(url)
      resp = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
      @json_resp = JSON.parse(resp)
      @result = @json_resp["docs"]
    end
  end

  def search

  end

end
```

The view:

```
<b>Pdf:</b> <%= link_to item["resource_name"], asset_path("/assets/documents/pdf/" + item["resource_name"]), :target => "_blank", :class => "links" %>
```

Log:

```
Started GET "/show_pdf/%2Fassets%2Fdocuments%2Fpdf%2F2018%2003%20Technical%20Conformance%20Guide%20v4.1.pdf" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-08-07 14:34:11 +0200

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/show_pdf/%2Fassets%2Fdocuments%2Fpdf%2F2018%2003%20Technical%20Conformance%20Guide%20v4.1.pdf"):
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
  web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
  web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  quiet_assets (1.1.0) lib/quiet_assets.rb:27:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.10) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.10) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.6) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.10) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:120:in `call'
  rack (1.6.10) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.6) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
  rack (1.6.10) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.6.10) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  rack (1.6.10) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
  /Users/jakublemiszewski/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:140:in `service'
  /Users/jakublemiszewski/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:96:in `run'
  /Users/jakublemiszewski/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/server.rb:296:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: Take a look at this, bit more elegant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41321630/891359

Answer (score 0):

Controller Action

```
def inline_pdf
  // read the params from the routes item["resource"]
  and then read the full path of the file by
  // File.expand_path(item["resource"])
  send_data(File.expand_path(item["resource"], disposition: 'inline', type: 'application/pdf')
end
```

View

```
<%= link_to item["resource_name"], inline_pdf_path(item["resource_name"])%>
```

routes

```
get "/inline_pdf/:name" => "controller_name#inline_pdf", as: :inline_pdf
```

Comment: I posted the only diff is that I change the name to show_pdf only change I did

Comment: Tried same error Route error
My route `Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root to: 'searches#index'

  get "/show_pdf/:name" => "searches#show_pdf", as: :show_pdf
end`

Comment: Take a look at this - What I have done is, I have added a link and upon clicking you can view the PDF inline. Place a file in public folder and add that file in your view - https://github.com/Kedarnag13/show_pdf

Comment: Are you uploading files and saving the path of the file in your database ? If you are storing that in DB, then I'll make the necessary changes as you have done and you can check it out.